# release background drawable in onpause

Tags: java, android

What is the proper way to release a drawable and manage it's lifecycle in an activity?  I'm trying to clear my bitmap because i see some memory related crashes.

I do:

```
private static bitmap;

    public void onResume() {

            view.setBackgroundDrawable( new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap));

    }

    public void onPause() {
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(null); // What is the best way to do this?
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap=null;

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from logcat?

Comment: @Andre,  i just noticed when inflating layout with large bitmaps my app was crashing so i'm just trying to do general clean up of bitmaps and wondering the best way to keep clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way. However you might add some more tweaks.

1. You set bitmap to null but the VM garbage collection might only trigger when you already try to reload the image. So in you onPause you can use: `System.gc()` to tell the GC that you need it. However it is not guranted that it will come.
2. with API 14+ use `android:largeHeap="true"`in your XML **only if you really need it**. This will increase the allowed size of the heap for your app.
3. Do you really need that big pictures? Try to make them smaller, use density dependent coding. Try to shrink it before loading ...